# Operator overloading complex numbers - additional function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to understand the idea of operator overloading, I'm getting to the point when it's all coming together and I might get the the hang of it, but...

I'm struggling to understand some piece of code which uses + operator, which has been overloaded so that it will add complex numbers, the code is pretty straightforward.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 


class complex {
  protected:
  double Re, Im;

public:
  complex() : Re(0.0), Im(0.0) {} 
  complex(double Re, double Im) : Re(Re), Im(Im) {} 
  double getRe() const { return Re; }
  double getIm() const { return Im; }
  friend complex operator+(const complex&, const complex&); 
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const complex&); 
};

complex operator+(const complex& a, const complex& b) {
double r, i;
r = a.getRe() + b.getRe();
i = a.getIm() + b.getIm();
**return complex(r, i);** // *** CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN THIS BIT ? ***
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const complex &a) {
  out << "(" << a.getRe() << ", " << a.getIm() << ")" << endl;
  return out;
}

int main(void) {
  complex a(1,2), b(3,4), c;
  c = a+b;
  cout << c << endl;
```

}

I can't understand what exactly line 23 does:

```
return complex(r, i);
```

Overloaded adding operator supposed to return some value, as it has been clarified it supposed to be value of complex type.

So that it will look like declared in complex class, **but does it have something to do with constructor ?**

I mean how the compilator will now, what is the type 'complex' look like, since it's a name of a class, does it have something to do with class' constructor ?

Do constructors define the values which are the type of a class ?

For instance, we have class cold dog.

the value that will a type of a class called dog, would be like this:

dog value

**Does constructor within dog class defines the definition of value, how it looks like, what information does it store ?**

2. How can I overload ostream operator >> (cin) so that the user can specify its own values of complex numbers ?

Thanks !

Comment: You are supposed to ask **one** question.

Comment: You do know that C++ already have [complex numbers in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: As for *one* of your problem, you don't see any similarity between the "call" `complex(r, i)` and one of the constructors?

Comment: Constructors are usually explained in introductory C++ books. Also, don't say "using namespace std", especially if you don't know every single name that lives under the `std` namespace in the current and future C++ standards.

Comment: Don't learn C++ by trial and error. Read a book *and* try things out at the same time. Stroustrup is my favourite.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, read carefully the entire post - I did try to point out similarity between constructor and 'function calling', I need further explanatior or confirmation that my guess is correct one.

Comment: Constructors are a different beast. :) A matching constructor might be used instead of the assignment operator (`operator=()`), but they're not really related; they might just do similar things based on the actual code (which is really up to you).

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't say `using namespace std;`, especially if you want to define a class with the same name as an entity which lives in `std`.  There is already an `std::complex`.

Answer (score 0):

comment inscribed

```
complex operator+(const complex& a, const complex& b) {
double r, i;
r = a.getRe() + b.getRe(); // real part of the result
i = a.getIm() + b.getIm(); // imaginary part of the result
return complex(r, i); // you are returning (by value) a complex number formed from r and i
}
```

here, complex(r, i) creates a temporary complex object (calling the constructor to initialize) and return by value will create another temporary to use in the caller.

Overloading >>
declare as

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream&, complex&);
```

and define as:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& i, complex& c) {
  i >> c.Re >> c.Im;
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading has nothing to do with the constructor (neither the default one nor the copy or move constructors; the results might get copied though depending on the signature).

You basically tell the computer how to apply some specific operator/operation to objects of your class (or any combination with other values depending on the parameters available).

**So how does it work?**

Pretty simple. Let's assume the compiler finds a construct such as this:

```
result = first + second;
```

In this example we've got two operators, so essentially two steps:

- `operator+()` with `first` and `second`.
- `operator=()` (the assignment operator (if defined) or copy constructor) to assign the `result`.

So the compiler knows it will need to find matching `operator+()` signature based on the types of `first` and `second`. Basically there are two basic ways this could be defined:

- Either as a member of `first`'s class: `... FirstClass::operator+(const SecondClass &secondObject)` (my preferred way)
- or as a standalone function with two arguments: `... operator+(const FirstClass &firstObject, const SecondClass &secondObject)` (the only way to do it for classes you can't update, like those residing within the standard library (`std` namespace)).

I've omitted the return types since those are really up to you. Even though it's not recommended, you can return pretty much anything, you don't even have to "add" using `operator+()` for example.

In your example with complex numbers, the compiler will look for `... complex::operator+(const complex &other)`, `... operator+(const complex &left, const complex &right)`, or any variation with compatible operators that might be used using implicit casting.

---

For the second part of your question involving `someInputStream >> myComplexNumber` - **How to implement a missing operator?**

Since you don't have direct access to modify the input stream class (whatever it actually is), you'll have to define it outside a class with two parameters. Applying the knowledge above it becomes pretty trivial:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, complex &number);
```

First a short explanation why the references in parameters aren't `const`: You'll have to modify them both. This contradicts typical mathematical convention, e.g. when you evaluate `c = a + b`, you won't modify neither `a` nor `b`. While this sounds odd, it's as is. For the stream this is due to the stream being modified (even if you only move the pointer to the current position in your stream). As for the complex number, it's due to the assignment being done.

The return type in this situation has to be `istream &`, because you'll have to return the stream object again. This is by convention. Theoretically (as mentioned above), you won't have to do this, but by doing so you implement the expected behavior, which allows the user to chain these operators to read multiple things, e.g. something like `myStream >> complex1 >> complex2;` (this essentially evaluates to `myStream >> complex1;` and `myStream >> complex2`).

Once you have the signature of your function, you just have to fill the contents, which is again trivial to do:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, complex &number) {
    input >> number.Re >> number.Im; // query the real and imaginary parts one after the other as doubles (since that's the members' type)
    return input; // return the stream again
}
```

If you've got issues understanding this (quite basic) concept, try to keep in mind that the operators are just a convenient way to write those overloaded functions. Instead of using `+` you could use `operator+()` as well for example.

The following two lines are essentially the same thing:

```
complexResult = complexNumber1 + complexNumber2;
complexResult = operator+(complexNumber1, complexNumber2);
```

The same is true for other operators, like `>>`, `||`, `&`, etc.

Comment: Extraordinary explanation, thank you very much. The best bit: " the results might get copied though depending on the signature)." this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{ private :
 int real ;
 int imag ;
 public :
complex(int real=0 , int imag=0)
{
    this->real=real;
    this->imag=imag;
}

complex operator +(complex ob2)
{  complex ob3;
    ob3.real=real + (ob2.real);
    ob3.imag=imag + (ob2.imag);
    return ob3; }
 void out()
{ cout<<real<<" + "<<imag<<"i"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
int real_1,imag_1;
int real_2,imag_2;
cout<<"real part Enter    ";cin>>real_1;
cout<<"imaginary part Enter  ";cin>>imag_1;
complex ob(real_1,imag_1);
cout<<"real part Enter    ";cin>>real_2;
cout<<"imaginary part Enter  ";cin>>imag_2;
complex ob2(real_2,imag_2);
complex ans;
ans=ob+ob2;
    ans.out();`   `
}
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.